# Opening a txt file in Python on a Mac

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x

I am trying to open and read in the data from a txt file using Python. So far I have the following code:

```
infile = open("/Users/jessicazahra/Desktop/University/Week\ 7/unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
outfile=open("/Users/jessicazahra/Desktop/University/Week\ 7/sorted_fruits.txt","w")
```

I keep receiving an error stating:

```
File "/Users/jessicazahra/Desktop/University/Week 7/sort_fruits.py", line 1, in <module>
    infile = open("/Users/jessicazahra/Desktop/University/Week\ 7/unsorted_fruits.txt", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/jessicazahra/Desktop/University/Week\\ 7/unsorted_fruits.txt'
```

I am using a mac and Python 3.4.1. I have a feeling something is wrong with my directory path but I cannot find what the problem might be though. The file is placed in a folder on my desktop. Any help would be much appreciated!!

Comment: Not sure what the backslash (\\) is doing in your filename, try removing that?

Comment: Sweet! That was the problem. Have no idea how that got there, thank you so much!

Comment: In almost any language, even sh (the shell you use on the terminal), you don't need backslashes inside quoted strings. In many languages (sh, C, etc.), an unnecessary backslash is ignored—`'\ '` and `' '` are the same string—but in Python, an unnecessary backslash is treated as a literal backslash.

Answer (score 3):

The `\` escape isn't needed when the file path is in a string.

Change `/Week\ 7/` to `/Week 7/`

Answer (score 0):

You can use os.path.expanduser() to do that. Also include '~' in your path.

here's a snippet of code where I'm trying to open a file on my desktop called movie_quotes.txt and read from it:

```
import os 

 def rename_files():
     file_to_open = os.path.expanduser('~/Desktop/movie_quotes.txt')
     f = open(file_to_open)
     print(f.read())

rename_files()
```